# Black Screen while using textureview and android Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to create a custom camera application. I am using textureView with Camera2 api. But when I am opening the application, only black screen is shown. When I click on "click picture" button It captures proper image and screen again goes black. I need to get proper image preview in place of black screen.

Comment: Your question is poorly explained and includes no code at all. It's really hard to help you with the above description.

Answer (score 0):

You give very less information, but you can have a look at this example:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

In the example there is also used a `TextureView`.